# How to deploy ganache workspace

Tags: flutter, blockchain, ganache, ether

I am having a flutter project where I have written code for Ethereum transfer. The problem is it is only working for static rpc URL like I have given IP address of my wifi.

I am new to ganache, and I can't find any way in which I can deploy that project and need not use the static URL.

`String rpcUrl = "http://192.168.0.103:7545";`

Here instead of static IP 192.168.0.103, I want some URL that is deployed so I can access this workspace if it's not in this IP 192.168.0.103 too.

Answer (score 0):

If you need that variable to be accessed from the app, you can create a [TextField](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextField-class.html), which will accept the IP adress from user, and then connect to specified network.

Other solution - is to use fifferent variables for different environments (say dev/master), and specify the set of variables on the stage of app build. So that master version of your app is built with proper variables.